# Is there a way to programmatically grab a list of meeting attendees from Outlook?

Tags: perl, vbscript, outlook

I am trying to grab a list of meeting attendees from Outlook 2003. I am open to using any language that would be appropriate. Scripting languages are preferable. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The information is exposed through the outlook COM interface so any language that can talk COM would work fine.

I once wrote a piece of code that did just this (and some more), and you can [see the source yourself](http://code.google.com/p/tiecal/source/browse/trunk/OutlookManager.cs#75).

If you can't be bothered to look through that code, in a nutshell you do:

```
// Also, don't forget to add a project reference to the outlook COM object
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

...

var outlookNS = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
var calendar = outlookNS.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

foreach (AppointmentItem item in calendar.Items)
{
    // Mandatory attendees (in the "To:" field)
    foreach (var attendee in item.Recipents)
      Console.WriteLine("Attendee {0}", attendee);

    // Optional Attendees (in the "CC:" field)
    foreach (var attendee in item.OptionalAttendees)
      Console.WriteLine("Attendee {0}", attendee);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In perl you would use Win32::OLE.

See for examle [this link](http://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol3_2/tpj0302-0008.html) and of course the documentation that comes with that module.

You should also be able to simply rewrite the VB code given above to perl using Win32::OLE.

And also see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78916/outlook-perl-win32ole-how-do-you-select-calendar-entries-sorted-by-date).